# What is the most efficient way to display 30 features in Openlayers and having them update every 1 sec?

Tags: openlayers-2

I have data in PostGIS of GPS coords and I want to show in OL 2.13 in real time (the GPS device transmit data to the server every 1 second) - also have Geoserver if needed.

My current solution is this and I was wondering if there is better way ?

```
 var coords = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("coords", {
    projection: epsg4326,
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: http://xxx/yyy/getGeoJson.php,
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
    }),     
    styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({ 'default': {            
        externalGraphic: 'resources/images/${iconName}',
        graphicWidth: 175,
        graphicHeight: 173,
        graphicOpacity: 0,
        label: '${gpsName}',
        fontColor: 'black',
        fontSize: '12px',
        fontFamily: 'Courier New, monospace',
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    }
    })
});
```

and I just redraw the layer each second.

Is there better way / correct way to do such a thing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the OpenLayers.Strategy.Refresh and compare the performance with your solution:

```
 var realtime = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Realtime", {
     strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed(),
         new OpenLayers.Strategy.Refresh({
             force: true,
             interval: 1000
         })
     ],
     protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
         url: "http://wanderdrone.appspot.com",  // Test-API
         format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
     }),
 });
```

I have put it into a jsfiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/ky91y9Lx/ ) to show a bit more of the code but as I can't use the OpenLayers.ProxyHost on jsfiddle the request is blocked. You'll still see in the console that the Request is sent every second. On my server the request works as I have added wanderdrone.appspot.com to my allowed hosts.
[image]

Comment: Thx , I guess its similar to timer but more elegant way :) 
Still I like the solution !